# Why cast to generic type takes effect?

Tags: java, generics

On [Java revisited](http://javarevisited.blogspot.tw/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html) ,a code excerpt goes below:

```
class Holder<T>{
  private T[] contents;
  private int index = 0;
  public Holder(int size){
    //contents = new T[size]; //compiler error - generic array creation
    contents = (T[]) new Object[size]; //workaround - casting Object[] to generic Type
  }...}
```

It is for generic array creation, but according to type erasure (I checked it on java online tutorial), `T` ends into `Object` at class compiled, so the cast `(T[])` would ends into
`(Object[])`, and that seems take **no difference to without casting**.

So what is the function of that casting or any special meaning for casting? any hint is thankful.

Comment: If you try without the cast, you will immediately see why it is there

Comment: Casting doesn't do anything at run time.  It's not the same thing as type conversion.  What it does is to tell the compiler to treat a particular expression as if its type were something different.

Comment: oh it just seems like just a placeholder for compiler, sorry for stupid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cast is required to tell the compiler that the assignment is Ok from our side. Else it will show you compiler error.

Due to type erasure, the type parameter `T` is replaced with it's erasure at compile time.
The erasure of an unbounded type parameter is `Object`, whereas the erasure of the bounded type parameter is the type denoting the upper bound. So, if your type parameter in class had an upper bound - `Holder<T extends Number>`, then the erasure of `T` will be `Number`. That means, `T` will be replaced with `Number` by the compiler.

So, in this case, since `T` in unbounded, its erasure is `Object`. So, it is replaced with `Object` by the compiler.

Even though the casting removes the compiler error, the compiler would still show you a warning of Unchecked Cast. Because, the cast is not type safe, and would fail at runtime with `ClassCastException` in case you instantiate the generic type using `String` type parameter.

Try this:

```
Holder<String> stringHolder = new Holder<>(5);
String[] contents = stringHolder.getContents();  // ClassCastException
```

---

A safer way to create generic array is using `Array.newInstance` method. You need to pass `Class<T>` parameter to your constructor, and then use the following code:

```
public Holder(int size, Class<T> clazz){
    contents = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, size);
}
```

Here also you will see the `Unchecked Cast` warning. But that is harmless.

Even safer way is not at all to create a array whose component type is a type parameter. You can rather use an `ArrayList<T>` instead.

---

**Reference:**

- [Java Generic FAQs - Angelika Langer](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeParameters.html#Can%20I%20create%20an%20array%20whose%20component%20type%20is%20a%20type%20parameter?)

Comment: "Here also you will see the Unchecked Cast warning. But that is harmless." No it isn't. Try passing `int.class` in as `clazz`.

Comment: "You need to pass Class<T> parameter to your constructor" The thing is that the `Holder` class doesn't need to know the type parameter to perform its function. So forcing the user to pass in a class object is not ideal.

Comment: thanks,and I just now found it's a bad design due to unable to getContents, that's terrible.

Answer (score 1):

T is just a placeholder.  You can't instantiate it which is while the compile error exists. At compile time you need to tell the compiler what the placeholder presents.  In the case of the code excerpt, the placeholder is anything.

Answer (score 1):

The cast is present to *get rid of* **compilation error**. And its an **unchecked** way of creating generic array.

Even the `ArrayList` follows the same method. You can have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328546/why-cast-to-generic-type-takes-effect#18328546) to see both checked and unchecked methods

Answer (score 0):

If you consider that after type erasure all type parameters end up as simple `Object`s, your question is about the use of Java Generics as a whole.  In my opinion, these are:

1. Documentation / inter-developer communication / legibility / maintainability.
2. Avoid logic errors as early as possible (i.e. statically).
3. Reduce testing requirements / allow to refocus testing efforts in more transcendental aspects and made the code more robust.

Unfortunately, it was difficult to fit Generics in Java maintaining full backwards compatibility and other objectives at that point.  The result is that `new T[size]` is invalid.  The only alternative is `new Object[size]`.  The cast `(T[])` is to tell the compiler and other developers that that's exactly what you intended.  In particular, the compiler will not emit a warning message in this particular line (which is much safer than  globally disabling this kind of checks).