# Internal functioning of Type Erasure in Generics

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

In `How Generics works in Java` section of [this](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/generics-java-example-tutorial.html)  it says

> Java compiler, when it sees code  written using Generics it completely erases that code
>       and covert it into raw type i.e. code without Generics. All type related information is
>       removed during erasing. So your ArrayList becomes plain old ArrayList  prior to 
>       JDK 1.5, formal type parameters e.g.  or  gets replaced by either Object or 
>       Super Class of the Type.

My question is about the last line - `formal type parameters e.g. <K, V> or <E> gets replaced by either Object or Super Class of the Type`.

In which case are they replaced by Object and in which case they are replaced by the Super Class of the object type?

**Update :**

What happens when we have wild card like below?

```
List<? extends Foo>
```

Comment: You check check this answer of @RohitJain  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18328546/why-cast-to-generic-type-takes-effect/18328627#18328653

Comment: It says **The erasure of an unbounded type parameter is Object, whereas the erasure of the bounded type parameter is the type denoting the upper bound.** I am not getting it can you give an example.

Comment: The ? still extends Foo. The answers are still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already know what the erasure is. The erasure is written `|T|`, so `|List<String>|` is `List`. Type variables, meaning mentionings of formal type parameters, are erased to the erasure of their left-most bound. The most general form of a formal type parameter `T` is `T extends A1 & A2 & ...`, where `A1`to `An` are `T`s bounds.

For Example

```
public abstract class Copyable<T extends Copyable<T> & Cloneable> {
    public T copy() { /* ... */ }
}
```

The `T` in copy would be erased to the erasure of its left-most bound. That is `|Copyable<T>| = Copyable`.

Simpler bounds may be

- **single bound** as in `class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`: The left most bound is the single bound, the erasure is `|Enum<E>| = Enum`.
- **no bound** as in `class ArrayList<E>`: `E` really has an implicit bound of `Object` (`class ArrayList<E extends Object>`), so the erasure is `|Object| = Object`.

**Edit**: In case of a `List<? extends Foo>` you'd be erasing the entire thing; and the erasure of `List<? extends Foo>` is `|List|`.

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an unbounded type `List<T>` the erasure will be the type `Object`.

In the case of a bounded type `List<T extends Foo>`, the erasure will be `Foo`.

Comment: @AniketThakur You asked a question and received three valid answers. Then you changed the question and had to post comments on each answer. The lesson to learn here is - please don't edit your question to ask something additional. Post a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a class called

```
class Holder<T>{
   T obj;
}
```

after **type erasure**, it looks like below, cause `Object` replaces *unbounded generic type* `T`

```
class Holder{
   Object obj;
}
```

Lets say you have class called

```
class Holder<T extends Cloneable>{
   T obj;
}
```

after **type erasure** it will be

```
class Holder{
   Cloneable obj;
}
```